# Break PDF booklet into pages

Tags: pdf, page-breaking, printing

I have a PDF with booklet-odered pages (like the one below). I would like to break these **PDF A4 pages** back into the original **twice as many PDF A5 pages**.

```
|-------| PDF page 1
| 8   1 |
|-------|

|-------| PDF page 2
| 2   7 |
|-------|

|-------| PDF page 3
| 6   3 |
|-------|

|-------| PDF page 4
| 4   5 |
|-------|
```

Comment: May be this thread in comp.text.tex could help you: [Splitting 2 pages/page landscape postscript file into two single page portrait pages](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topicsearchin/comp.text.tex/group:comp.text.tex$20AND$20psnup$20AND$20after:%22$20%22$20AND$20before:%22$20%22/comp.text.tex/wv_lnH1mMaw)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution via `tikz` and `graphicx`. Two compilations are required. `gen.pdf` is your booklet PDF file.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\foreach \page in {1,...,4}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \ifodd\page
    \node at (current page)
    {\includegraphics[page=\page,trim=148.5mm 0 0 0]{gen.pdf}};
    \else
    \node at (current page)
    {\includegraphics[page=\page,trim=0 0 148.5mm 0]{gen.pdf}};
    \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \newpage
}
\foreach \page in {4,...,1}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \ifodd\page
    \node at (current page)
    {\includegraphics[page=\page,trim= 0 0 148.5mm 0]{gen.pdf}};
    \else
    \node at (current page)
    {\includegraphics[page=\page,trim= 148.5mm 0 0 0]{gen.pdf}};
    \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \newpage
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, after some tweaking it works for me. For the tweaks, see my CW answer.

Answer (score 5):

Modification of the solution by *PolGab*, I got away the `tikzpicture` part which is completely unnecessary IMO, and I use `tikz` only for `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\placepage#1{%
\leavevmode\kern-0.25in{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \page in {1,...,4}{
    \ifodd\page
    \placepage{\includegraphics[page=\page,trim=148.5mm 0 0 0]{y.pdf}}
    \else
    \placepage{\includegraphics[page=\page,trim=0 0 148.5mm 0]{y.pdf}}
    \fi
  \newpage
}
\foreach \page in {4,...,1}{
    \ifodd\page
    \placepage{\includegraphics[page=\page,trim= 0 0 148.5mm 0]{y.pdf}}
    \else
    \placepage{\includegraphics[page=\page,trim= 148.5mm 0 0 0]{y.pdf}}
    \fi
  \newpage
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tikz` is certainly not necessary... but it is convenient to properly position the elements. Are you sure that your A5 page contents are perfectly centered (vertically and horizontally) ? Why -0.25in ?

Comment: Instead of `\usepackage{tikz}` you could only use `\usepackage{pgffor}` which provides `\foreach` command without other `TiKZ` tools and commands. `pgffor` package is part of `TiKZ`.

Comment: @PolGab sorry to say that, but _your_ code gave me completely wrong placement.

Comment: @tohecz A wrong placement is the result of the first compilation. With a second compilation, placement should be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

... and here are detailed descriptions how you can do that with the help of Ghostscript:

- [**Linux-based tool to chop PDFs into multiple pages**](https://superuser.com/a/192293/40894) (Superuser.com)
- [**Freeware to split a pdf's pages down the middle?**](https://superuser.com/a/235401/40894) (Superuser.com)
- [**Convert PDF 2 sides per page to 1 side per page**](https://superuser.com/a/189109/40894) (Superuser.com)